# Visual Basic Help with my Game

Tags: vb.net

I am building a game in Visual Basic called Battleship. I have 100 buttons (10 rows x 10 columns) and what I want the user to do, is be able to click on a button and a function called `IsCreated` (which is a Boolean) turns True for the certain button.

Two questions:
1. How do I create this function ?
2. How do I make the button that is clicked have IsCreated turn from true into false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic way would be to assign each button a number & use that in a function call from onClick(). You'd just have a global array of booleans (I used boardPosition)

`Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
 Handles button1.Click

   boardPosition(1) = IsCreated(1)


End Sub`

Then just have:

`Protected Function IsCreated(byVal buttonNumberClicked as integer)

    If boardPosition(buttonNumberClicked) Then

       return true

    else

       return false

    End If

End Function`

This is assuming you've just created 100 buttons...Not an elegant solution but it'll work.

**Edit:** Clean up.

Comment: Ok, this helps. I know its not elegant, but the TableLayoutPanel doesn't help whatsoever. Thanks for the help however appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I would create the buttons programatically and add them to a dictionary or list to keep track of them.  You'll probably want some kind of class to hold all the information about each grid cell instead of just an array of booleans.  Add the following to a blank form1.

```
Dim IsCreated(99) As Boolean
Dim Buttons As New Dictionary(Of String, Button)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    For i As Integer = 0 To 99
        Dim B As New Button
        Me.Controls.Add(B)
        B.Height = 30
        B.Width = 40
        B.Left = (i Mod 10) * 41
        B.Top = (i \ 10) * 31
        B.Text = Chr((i \ 10) + Asc("A")) & i Mod 10 + 1
        Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
        B.Tag = i
        AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim B As Button = sender
    IsCreated(B.Tag) = True
    B.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```